# QDockwidgets beside each others

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

How can I make UI like this

[image: What I mean]

I tried through the code and the designer but I couldn't

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i was able to create the same layout by dragging and dropping in qt designer
this is the ui code with layout manager and with ability to resize docks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Frame</class>
 <widget class="QFrame" name="Frame">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>628</width>
    <height>604</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Frame</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
   <item>
    <widget class="QSplitter" name="splitter_2">
     <property name="orientation">
      <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
     </property>
     <widget class="QSplitter" name="splitter">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
      </property>
      <widget class="QDockWidget" name="dockWidget">
       <property name="minimumSize">
        <size>
         <width>150</width>
         <height>0</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);</string>
       </property>
       <widget class="QWidget" name="dockWidgetContents"/>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QDockWidget" name="dockWidget_2">
       <property name="minimumSize">
        <size>
         <width>150</width>
         <height>0</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(32, 74, 135);</string>
       </property>
       <widget class="QWidget" name="dockWidgetContents_2"/>
      </widget>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::NoFrame</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QDockWidget" name="dockWidget_4">
      <property name="minimumSize">
       <size>
        <width>120</width>
        <height>581</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(239, 41, 41);</string>
      </property>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="dockWidgetContents_4"/>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QDockWidget" name="dockWidget_3">
      <property name="minimumSize">
       <size>
        <width>120</width>
        <height>581</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(115, 210, 22);</string>
      </property>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="dockWidgetContents_3"/>
     </widget>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

after you save it to a file you can change it to py file by running

```sh
pyuic5 -x file.ui -o file.py
```

or use it directly with uic module as musicamante said in the comments

Comment: This doesn't seem a good result: there's no [layout manager](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) set, as soon as the window is resized docks would become hidden, or lots of parts of the window would be unnecessarily empty. You should properly set a main layout [in Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html). Also, the pyuic step is not required, as long as the `uic` module is used.

Comment: @musicamante then it should be like this